# Resolved: C and Python: fill a file empty through mmap

Tags: python, c, file, mmap, shared

I want create a shared mapped file between C (that create the mapped file and only read from it) and python (that write and fill the mapped file). I have this C code :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *shared;
    int fd = -1;
    fd = open("hello.txt", O_RDWR, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("unable to open");
        return 0;
    }

    shared = (char *)mmap(NULL, 1, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    system("python /home/giuseppe/Documents/test_mmap/mappalo.py");
    printf("C CODE: %c\n",shared[0]);

}
```

and this is a python code:

```
import sys
import os
import mmap

with open( "hello.txt", "wb" ) as fd:
    fd.write("1")
with open( "hello.txt", "r+b" ) as fd:
    mm = mmap.mmap(fd.fileno(), 0, flags=mmap.MAP_SHARED, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE, offset=0)
    print("content read from file")
    print(mm.readline())
    mm[0] = "01"
    mm.close()
    fd.close()
```

when I executed the C code, I get this error:

```
content read from file
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/giuseppe/Documents/test_mmap/mappalo.py", line 11, in <module>
    mm[0] = "01"
IndexError: mmap assignment must be single-character string
C CODE: 1
```

How can I write from python code a long string in a mapped file and then read it from C code?

Thank you so much for your time

**UPDATE**
I want to write two strings, so I write this code:

```
arr = bytes("Hello123;", 'utf-8')
arr1 = bytes("Hello412;", 'utf-8')
size = sys.getsizeof(arr) + sys.getsizeof(arr1)

with buf:
    buf[:size] = struct.pack('ss', arr1, arr)
```

But I have the following error:

```
IndexError: mmap slice assignment is wrong size
```

**UPDATE 2**
Thank you to Sam Mason that allow me to resolve. This is the code:

C code:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  int fd = open("hello.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
  if (fd == -1) {
      perror("unable to open");
      return 1;
  }

  if (ftruncate(fd, 4096) < 0) {
    perror("unable to set length");
    return 1;
  }

  int *shared = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  //system("python3.7 mappalo.py");
  printf("C CODE: %s\n", shared);
  return 0;
}
```

Python code:

```
import mmap
import struct

with open('hello.txt', 'r+b') as fd:
    buf = mmap.mmap(fd.fileno(), 4096, access=mmap.ACCESS_DEFAULT)

arr = bytes("Hello123;", 'utf-8')
arr1 = bytes("Hello412;", 'utf-8')
size = len(arr) + len(arr1)
types = str(len(arr))+'s' + str(len(arr1))+'s'

with buf:
    buf[:size] = struct.pack(types, arr1, arr)
```

Comment: Can you try `mm[0:] = b"01"` (taken from the first example on https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/mmap.html)

Comment: @TomDalton your code produce this error: ```File "/home/giuseppe/Documents/test_mmap/mappalo.py", line 11, in <module>
    mm[0:] = b"01"
IndexError: mmap slice assignment is wrong size```

Comment: Try `mm[0:2] = b"01"` then. I'm not sure if/how you can use the mmap to extend the size of the existing file tho.

Comment: e.g. you created the file with 1 byte in it, but it looks like you're then trying to use the mmap to overwrite 2 bytes into it, which i'm not sure if you can do.

Comment: @TomDalton I edited the instruction to create a shared file, like this: ```shared = (char *)mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);``` but it produce the same error

Comment: If I use `mm[0:]=b"01"` it produce this error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/giuseppe/Documents/test_mmap/mappalo.py", line 11, in <module>
    mm[0:] = b"01"
IndexError: mmap slice assignment is wrong size```

Comment: You can't use mmap to resize the file. I think you want `mm[0] = b'\x01'` if you want to write one byte of `0x01` value to the file.

Comment: @giupardeb just noticed you said "write from python code a long string in a mapped file" at the end.  if you really mean you want to transfer an arbitrary string from Python to C, then this is somewhat ill-defined. you'd (at least) need to specify what encoding is being used, how the position & length is specified in the file.

Comment: `getsizeof` isn't the number of bytes in a `bytes` object, you need to use `len`.  to debug this just try short bits of code in an interactive environment (e.g. the REPL or a Jupyter notebook) or add some `print` statements to your code.

Comment: @SamMason You're right, but I just tried to use `len` but didn't work, I got the same error above

Comment: try printing the output of `struct.pack` it's probably 2 bytes long, i.e. just the first byte in each array.  I'm going to stop answering trivial questions like this, you need to learn what's going on

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your time..I will write when I will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're doing various strange things in both your C code and Python code.  I'll start with some code that "works":

first, C code:

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  int fd = open("hello.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
  if (fd == -1) {
      perror("unable to open");
      return 1;
  }

  if (ftruncate(fd, 1024) < 0) {
    perror("unable to set length");
    return 1;
  }

  int *shared = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  system("python mmap-test.py");
  printf("C CODE: %i %i\n", shared[0], shared[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

I've trimmed headers a bit, and make sure that the file has some data in it (in this case it'll be lazily filled with zeros by the kernel).  I also treat it as an array of `int`s as  a single byte is pointless to transfer.  also, you're generally recommended not to cast from `void*` to another type.  I also set the permission mask to something sensible, zero will just break things later.

next Python code:

```py
import mmap
import struct

with open('hello.txt', 'r+b') as fd:
    buf = mmap.mmap(fd.fileno(), 1024, access=mmap.ACCESS_DEFAULT)

with buf:
    buf[:8] = struct.pack('ii', 123, 7901)
```

I just open it once, map the data in, encode two Python `int`s to a byte array of two C-`int`s.  the non-nesting of `with` statements is meant to show that `mmap` holds the file open on its own, but you might want to nest them in your own code.  your two `open`s in Python were also creating a second file (of the same name, replacing the C file) which was probably confusing things.  also you weren't writing the correct sized/typed data into the `mmap`ed space

Comment: Thank you so much for your work..Now the operation of mmap is more clear! But I want to write two strings, so I write this code:
```arr = bytes("Hello123;", 'utf-8')
arr1 = bytes("Hello412;", 'utf-8')
size = sys.getsizeof(arr) + sys.getsizeof(arr1)

with buf:
    buf[:size] = struct.pack('ss', arr1, arr)```

But I have the following error: `IndexError: mmap slice assignment is wrong size`

Comment: posting that much code in a comment is unreadable..  please edit your question and put it in there